# Determining the point and angle at which two circles intersect.

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, physics

I have recently started playing with canvas after seeing how easy it can be. My first project was just to keep a circle in its boundaries as it moves around. I made a few more things involving the movement of circles and now...

I'm currently working on bouncing two circles off of each other when they hit. You can see the example of that here: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/QQMgm/7/

However, I would like to use a little more real world physics. At the moment, when the circles hit each other they just reverse their path.

As shown here:

```
    // Dont be confused, this is just the Distance Formula
    // We compare the distance of the two circles centers to the sum of the radii of the two
    // circles. This is because we want to check when they hit each other on the surface
    // and not the center.
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c1.x - c2.x, 2) + Math.pow(c1.y - c2.y, 2));
    var r1       = c1.rad;
    var r2       = c2.rad;
    if (distance < r1 + r2) {
        // Change the slope of both circle
        // I would like to figure out a more effecience way of bouncing the circles back
        // However, I have no idea how to determine the angle the ball was struck,
        // and with that information bounce it off at that angle
        c1.xi = -c1.xi; // path is reversed
        c1.yi = -c1.yi;
        c2.xi = -c1.xi;
        c2.yi = -c1.yi;
    }
```

However, I would like the circles to go in opposite direction determined by the point and angle of intersection.

I am only in the 9th grade and not sure how the formula for something like this would look. But I know that it is possible because this kind of physics is present in many games. An example would be an 8-ball game. When the balls hit each other, they move across the table according to how the balls hit each other.

I would appreciate any tips on how to do this or if I should wait until I have a stronger understanding of Physics and Math in general.

Comment: If the circles have the same mass and speed, then the velocities just swap.  But if the speeds are different, things get more complicated.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thanks for the comment. But should the angle of intersection matter?

Comment: I don't think so.  Following Pixou, we can rotate everything (in our mind at least) so that the center of mass is moving to the right.  Since the mass and speed match, this means the vertical component of the velocities are exactly opposite.  Then when the circles hit, it's like they bounce off of a horizontal wall, so that the horizontal velocity doesn't change, and the vertical velocity is negated.  But this is exactly the velocity from the other circle.  Unrotate everything, and you're back in the reference frame where you started.

Answer (score 2):

too bad we can't draw a very simple scheme.
As far as physics is concerned, you know that the total momentum is conserved, see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum

There is a good illustration and formulas here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional
You can simplify formulas if the two object have the same weight.

so now, let's consider the reference frame in which c2 is fixed and center in (0,0).
c1 velocity in this reference would be :

```
c1.xfi=c1.xi-c2.xi
c1.yfi=c1.yi-c2.yi
```

Now you have a collision when the distance between the two is the sum of radius. Consider the tangent plane of the two circles.

You now have to decompose the velocity of c1 into a tangent component, which is conserved, and a perpendicular (following the line between c1 and c2), which is transfered to c2.

Then you need to go back to your original reference frame.

(sorry i didn't give you the exact formulas but they are on the links I provided)

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this myself, I would implement the motion using [Newtons law of restitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution). Essentially this is a coefficient that relates approach and separation speed of 2 particles before/after impact and it has a value that depends on the material properties of your particles.

Your analysis will essentially amount to identifying the point of impact, then breaking down the approach velocities into components that are parallel and perpendicular to the line of centres of the circle at the point of impact.

The momentum of the particles is conserved perpendicular to the line of centres (so the velocities in that direction remain unchanged by the collision) and the law of restitution applies to the velocities parallel to the line of centres. Thus if you fix the coefficient of restitution (it has to be between 0 and 1) to some value of your choice you can use this law to calculate the separation speeds along the line of centres of your particles after collision using the value of the approach speeds.

If your particles are all of the same mass and radius then the calculations become simpler. You can model elastic collisions by setting the coefficient to 1 (this indicates that separation speed of the particles is the same as the approach speed) which is probably the easiest place to start. By changing the value you will see different behaviour between particles after collisions.

Sorry not to be able to write this all down in formula for you, but this is not really the appropriate place for it. Living in the UK I have no idea what "9th grade" is so I can't assess if the above is too advanced for your current level of education. Here in the UK this type of problem would typically be covered at A-level mathematics education level.

Hopefully though it will give you an indication of the terms and topics that you can teach yourself/ research in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: 9th grade is about 14 years old.  9th grade math is anything from pre-algebra through algebra 2 or geometry or trigonometry.

Comment: @Teepeemm Oh right then all of that is probably a little too advanced.